# ボタンクリックの関数の処理が残ってしまう

Tags: javascript, jquery

ぐるなびapiを利用して、飲食店の検索ページを作成しました。

都道府県、飲食店の種類を指定して、検索ボタンをクリックすると、５００件ごとの検索結果（飲食店名、存在する地域、交通機関、最寄駅のリスト）が表示されるようなページを javascript(jQuery)を使って組み立てました。

「次の結果」ボタンクリックで、次の５００件の検索結果を表示する。「前の結果」ボタンクリックで、前の５００件の検索結果を表示するようにしています。

「次の結果」を連続してクリックすると、順調に次の検索結果が表示されるのですが、途中で「前の結果」をクリックして前へ戻ろうとすると、「前の結果」にもかかわらず、次の検索結果が表示されます。

ただし、それは１回のみで、その後「前の結果」を連続してクリックしていけば、前の結果が表示されていきます。

同様に「前の結果」を連続してクリックすると、順調に前の検索結果が表示されるのですが、途中で「次の結果」をクリックして次へ進もうとすると、「次の結果」にもかかわらず、前の検索結果が表示されます。

ただし、これも同様に１回のみで、その後「次の結果」を連続してクリックしていけば、次の結果が表示されていきます。

途中でボタンを切り替えると、直前のボタン処理で行った関数が残っているような感じです。途中でボタンを切り替えても、すぐに検索結果が反映されるようにしたいのですが、どなたかご教示いただけますか。

コード

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./gurunavi.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(function() {

    (function() {

      var $container = jQuery('.grid'); //wrapper要素指定

      var $inner = '.grid-item'; //inner要素指定

      var api_key = '個人のapiキーをここに入力';

      var hit_per_page_num = 500; //一度に表示する件数

      var offset_page_num = 1; //初期ページ

      var sort = 1; //ソート(名前順)

  　　var url_rest = 'http://api.gnavi.co.jp/RestSearchAPI/20150630/?callback=?'; //レストラン検索API

      var url_pref = 'http://api.gnavi.co.jp/master/PrefSearchAPI/20150630/?callback=?'; //エリアマスタ取得API

　　　var url_cat = 'http://api.gnavi.co.jp/master/CategoryLargeSearchAPI/20150630/?callback=?'; //カテゴリー取得API

      var params = {

        keyid: api_key,

        format: 'json',

      }  

      var params_shop = jQuery.extend({ }, params);

      params_shop.hit_per_page = hit_per_page_num;

      params_shop.offset_page = offset_page_num; 

      params_shop.sort = sort;

      var resultLooplength = 0; //店舗データ数判定

      var resultLoopnext = function(result) { //次ページの店舗データ出力

        document.getElementById("load_next").disabled = false;

        document.getElementById("load_back").disabled = false;

        resultLooplength = hit_per_page_num * (params_shop.offset_page - 1);

        if(resultLooplength < 0) {

          resultLooplength = 0;

          params_shop.offset_page = 1;

        }

        var res = "";

        res += "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>";

        res += "<tr><td align='center'>No.</td><td align='center'>店舗名（五十音順）</td><td align='center'>登録エリア</td><td align='center'>交通路線</td><td align='center'>最寄駅</td></tr>";

        for (var i in result.rest) {

          var elem = {

            name: result.rest[i].name, //店舗名取得

            url: result.rest[i].url, //ぐるなび店舗詳細ページURL取得

            area: result.rest[i].code.areaname_s, //エリア名取得

            line: result.rest[i].access.line, //路線名取得

            station: result.rest[i].access.station //最寄駅名取得

          }

          i++; 

          res += "<tr>";

          if(elem.area == '[object Object]') {

            elem.area = "情報提供なし";

　　　　　} else {

            elem.area = elem.area;

          }

          if(elem.line == '[object Object]') {

            elem.line = "情報提供なし";

　　　　　} else {

            elem.line = elem.line;

          }

          if(elem.station == '[object Object]') {

            elem.station = "情報提供なし";

　　　　　} else {

            elem.station = elem.station;

          }

    　resultLooplength++;

    　res += "<td>" + resultLooplength + "</td><td><a href='" + elem.url + "' target='_blank'>" + elem.name + "</a></td><td>" + elem.area + "</td><td>" + elem.line + "</td><td>" + elem.station + "</td>";

          res += "</tr>";

        }

        res += "</table>";

        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = res;

        var page_num = params_shop.offset_page + " ページ目";

        document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = page_num;

        if(resultLooplength >= result.total_hit_count) {

          alert("全店舗を表示しました。");

          document.getElementById("load_next").disabled = true;

          if(params_shop.offset_page == 1) {

            document.getElementById("load_back").disabled = true;

          } else {

            params_shop.offset_page--;

          }         

        }       

        params_shop.offset_page++;

      };

      var resultLoopback = function(result) { //前ページの店舗データ出力

        document.getElementById("load_next").disabled = false;

        document.getElementById("load_back").disabled = false;

        resultLooplength = hit_per_page_num * (params_shop.offset_page - 1);

        var res = "";

        res += "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>";

        res += "<tr><td align='center'>No.</td><td align='center'>店舗名（五十音順）</td><td align='center'>登録エリア</td><td align='center'>交通路線</td><td align='center'>最寄駅</td></tr>";

        for (var i in result.rest) {

          var elem = {

            name: result.rest[i].name, //店舗名取得

            url: result.rest[i].url, //ぐるなび店舗詳細ページURL取得

            area: result.rest[i].code.areaname_s, //エリア名取得

            line: result.rest[i].access.line, //路線名取得

            station: result.rest[i].access.station //最寄駅名取得

          }

          i++; 

          res += "<tr>";

          if(elem.area == '[object Object]') {

            elem.area = "情報提供なし";

　　　　　} else {

            elem.area = elem.area;

          }

          if(elem.line == '[object Object]') {

            elem.line = "情報提供なし";

　　　　　} else {

            elem.line = elem.line;

          }

          if(elem.station == '[object Object]') {

            elem.station = "情報提供なし";

　　　　　} else {

            elem.station = elem.station;

          }           
　　
          resultLooplength++; 

    　res += "<td>" + resultLooplength + "</td><td><a href='" + elem.url + "' target='_blank'>" + elem.name + "</a></td><td>" + elem.area + "</td><td>" + elem.line + "</td><td>" + elem.station + "</td>";

          res += "</tr>";

          if(resultLooplength == 1) {

            document.getElementById("load_back").disabled = true;

          }

        }  

        res += "</table>";

        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = res;

        var page_num = params_shop.offset_page + " ページ目";

        document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = page_num;

        params_shop.offset_page--;

      };

      var resultNum = function(result) { //取得件数を表示

        if (result.total_hit_count > 0) {

          jQuery('.total').html(resultLooplength + ' / ' + result.total_hit_count + ' の店舗を表示\n');

        } else {

          jQuery('.total').html('店舗がありません。');

        }

      };

      var resultPref = function(result) { //都道府県データをselect要素として生成

        for (var i in result.pref) {

          var pref_name = result.pref[i].pref_name;

          var pref_code = result.pref[i].pref_code;

          jQuery("[name = pref_name]").append('<option value="' + pref_code + '">' + pref_name + '</option>');

        }

      };

      var resultCat = function(result) { //カテゴリーデータをselect要素として生成

        for (var i in result.category_l) {

          var cat_name = result.category_l[i].category_l_name;

          var cat_code = result.category_l[i].category_l_code;

          jQuery("[name = cat_name]").append('<option value="' + cat_code + '">' + cat_name + '</option>');

        }

      };

      jQuery(window).on('load', function() {

        jQuery.getJSON(url_pref, params, function(result) { //都道府県データを取得し表示

          resultPref(result);

        })

        jQuery.getJSON(url_cat, params, function(result) { //カテゴリーデータを取得し表示 

          resultCat(result);

        })

      });

      jQuery("#load_next").on('click', function() {

        jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop, function(result) {

          resultLoopnext(result);

          resultNum(result);

        })

      });  

      jQuery("#load_back").on('click', function() {

        jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop, function(result) {

          resultLoopback(result);

          resultNum(result);

        })        

      });

      jQuery('[name = shop_search]').on('click', function() { //都道府県を変更して店舗データを再取得　

        resultLooplength = 0; //店舗データ数判定を初期化

        document.getElementById("load_next").disabled = false;

        document.getElementById("load_back").disabled = false;

        var pref_val = jQuery('[name = pref_name]').val(); //option要素のvalue(都道府県パラメータ)を取得

        var cat_val = jQuery('[name = cat_name]').val(); //option要素のvalue(カテゴリーパラメータ)を取得

        $container.empty(); //データ一覧を初期化

        params_shop.offset_page = 1; //ページ数を初期化

        params_shop.pref = pref_val; //都道府県パラメータを都道府県データ取得APIにセット

        params_shop.category_l = cat_val; //カテゴリーパラメータを大カテゴリーデータ取得APIにセット

        jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop, function(result) {

          resultLoopnext(result); 

          resultNum(result);

        })

      });

    }).call(this);

  }); 

  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <article class="wrap">

    <header class="header">

      <div class="inner">       

        <center>

          <span class="pref_search">

            都道府県&nbsp;&nbsp;                    

            <select name="pref_name"></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;

          </span>

          <span class="cat_search">

            ジャンル&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <select name="cat_name"></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <button type="button" name="shop_search">検 索</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <input type="button" id="load_back" value="前の結果">&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <input type="button" id="load_next" value="次の結果">

          </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;

          <span class="total"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;

          <span id="page"></span>

         </center>  

      </div>

    </header><br>

    <hr><br>

    <div class="content_outer">

      <div class="content_inner">

        <section>

          <div id="table"></div><br>

          <center>

            <a href="javascript:scrollTo(0, 0)"><input type="button" id="page_top" value="ページトップへ"></a>

          </center>   

        </section>

      </div>

    </div>

    <footer>

      <div class="container"></div>

    </footer>

  </article>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

※全くの勘違いだったので前の回答は削除しました

質問に書かれたコードから「前の結果」を押した時の処理を抜粋します。

```
jQuery("#load_back").on('click', function() {
  jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop, function(result) {
    resultLoopback(result);
    resultNum(result);
  })
});
```

そして `resultLoopback()` は次のようになっています。

```
var resultLoopback = function(result) { //前ページの店舗データ出力
  document.getElementById("load_next").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("load_back").disabled = false;
  resultLooplength = hit_per_page_num * (params_shop.offset_page - 1);

  // 略（resultの表示処理）

  params_shop.offset_page--;
};
```

今回表示する分の**API呼び出しを行った後に** `params_shop.offset_page` を更新していますね・・・？言い換えると、次にどのページが表示されるかを変更してしまっているのです。

- 「検索」 表示: 1ページ目 params_shop.offset_page: 2
- 「次の結果」 表示: 2ページ目 params_shop.offset_page: 3
- 「次の結果」 表示: 3ページ目 params_shop.offset_page: 4
- 「前の結果」 表示: 4ページ目 params_shop.offset_page: 3
- 「次の結果」 表示: 3ページ目 params_shop.offset_page: 4

「前の結果」というのはその時に取得・表示されるページを前ページにしたいのですから、**APIを呼び出す前に** `params_shop.offset_page` を更新しなければいけません。むしろ取得結果の表示ロジックは同じものが使えるはずです。

Comment: うまくいきました。本当にありがとう

Comment: @小林弘典 無事解決したようで何よりです。回答の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックしていただくと、その回答で解決したという目印になります。