# ボタンクリックの関数が残ってしまう。（新）

Tags: jquery

１０日ほど前に、ぐるなびの「前の結果」「次の結果」ボタンの表示の問題で投稿した者です。

Unarist様のおかげで、その問題は解決しました。ありがとうございました。

今度は、「先頭へ」と「最後へ」のボタンを作り、クリックすれば、それぞれ先頭と最後のページが表示されるようしたいです。「先頭へ」は以下のコードで、簡単に思い通りの結果が得られました。

```
jQuery("#load_first").on('click', function() {
   params_shop.offset_page = 1; // 先頭のページなので、１を指定        
     jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop, function(result) {
        resultLoopback(result);　// ５００件ごとに飲食店を表示（飲食店に連番でつけた番号、名前、地域、最寄駅など）
        resultNum(result);　// 現時点での飲食店の表示件数（トータル）を表示
      });
   });
```

ところが、「最後へ」については、以下のコードではうまくいかないようで、苦戦をしています。

```
jQuery("#load_last").on('click', function() {
   jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop, function(result) {
     if(result.total_hit_count % 500 == 0) {　
       params_shop.offset_page = Math.floor(result.total_hit_count / 500); 
     } else {
       params_shop.offset_page = Math.floor(result.total_hit_count / 500) + 1;
     }
     resultLoopnext(result);
     resultNum(result);
 });        

});
```

`if(result.total_hit_count % 500 == 0) {`　の部分の処理については、こうです。

飲食店のトータルのヒット数（例えば、１０００件、２０００件など、めったにないが）を５００で割った時に、余りが出なければ、`params_shop.offset_page`（現在のページ番号は）
`result.total_hit_count / 500` （トータルのヒット数を500で割る）　の値になる。

余りが出れば（たいてい、余りが出るものである）、`params_shop.offset_page`（現在のページ番号は）
`result.total_hit_count / 500 ＋　1`（トータルのヒット数を500で割った値に１を足す）　の値になる。

`if(result.total_hit_count % 500 == 0) {`　からの部分を

`jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop, function(result) {`　の処理の前に記述
すべきだと思って、最初はそのように記述したのですが、「最後へ」ボタンをクリックしても、まったく反応が
ありませんでした。

そこで、`jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop, function(result) {`　の中に記述すると
反応がありました。ですが、飲食店に連番でつけた番号が変わるだけで、肝心の店の名前や地域、最寄駅などが変わってくれません。

このように、肝心の部分が更新された状態で、表示させたいのですが、どうしたらいいでしょうか？

javascriptの全体のコードは、前回「ボタンクリックの関数が残ってしまう」の際に、投稿していますので、それを参考にしていただければと思います。

状況を把握していただいている unarsit 様に、ご返答願えたらと思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問の本旨とは異なりますが、最終ページの取得、`Math.ceil`で小数点以下繰り上げればいいのでは？

Comment: 関連：[ボタンクリックの関数の処理が残ってしまう](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29608)

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.getJSON`で取得しているのは**1ページ目の結果**でしかないからではないでしょうか。

もし、APIを叩いて最終ページを算出してそのページを取得したいのであれば、結果を触ってから**もう一度その最終ページのAPIを叩くひつようがある**でしょう。

(それよりも初回ロード時に変数等にページ数をキャッシュしておいたほうが手っ取り早い気はしますが。)

---

例）

```
   jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop).then(function(result) {
     params_shop.offset_page = Math.ceil(result.total_hit_count / 500);
     return jQuery.getJSON(url_rest, params_shop);
   }).then(function(result){
     resultLoopnext(result);
     resultNum(result);
   });
```